Why is Principal injected with @Context null or incomplete in my JAX-RS /login resource?
I am developing a Jakarta EE application using Open Liberty with JAX-RS for RESTful endpoints and JWT for authentication. I have implemented a ContainerRequestFilter to validate JWT tokens and set a custom SecurityContext. However, in my /login endpoint, the injected Principal is either incomplete (getName() is null) or throws an error, even though I am setting the SecurityContext properly in my filter.
JWT Authentication Filter
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final static Set<String> PUBLIC_PATHS = Set.of(
            "/auth/register",
            "/auth/login");

    private IUserDAO userDAO;
    private JWTService jwtService;

    @Context
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    }

    @Inject
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(IUserDAO userDAO, JWTService jwtService) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    /**
     * Checks the validity of JWT for every request that does not belong to the
     * "Public paths".
     * If there is no SecurityContext associated with current user, it creates one.
     */

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        UriInfo uriInfo = containerRequestContext.getUriInfo();
        System.out.println("JWT "+ containerRequestContext.getRequest());
        // Check if the path is public
        if (isPublicPath(uriInfo.getPath())) {
            return;
        }

        // Extract the Authorization header
        String authorizationHeader = containerRequestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization Header does not exist, or is invalid.");
        }

        // Extract token
        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length()).trim();

        try {
            // Validate and extract subject (email)
            String email = jwtService.extractSubject(token);

            if (email != null) {
                User user = userDAO.findUserByUserEmail(email).orElse(null);

                // Validate token and set SecurityContext if valid
                if (user != null && jwtService.isTokenValid(token, user)) {
                    containerRequestContext.setSecurityContext(new CustomSecurityContext(user));

                    System.out.println("SecurityContext set for user: " + containerRequestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal().getName());

                    return;
                } else {
                    throw new NotAuthorizedException("Invalid token.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("JWT Validated for user: " + email);
            System.out.println("Setting SecurityContext for: " + email);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Invalid token.");
        }
    }

    // Checks if a path belongs to public paths
    private boolean isPublicPath(String path) {
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        return PUBLIC_PATHS.stream().anyMatch(path::startsWith);
    }
}

Custom Security Context
@RequestScoped
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    private User user;

    
    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        // Role-based checks not implemented
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return true; // Assume HTTPS is used
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return "Bearer";
    }
}


Login Resource
    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response loginUser(UserLoginDTO userLoginDTO, @Context Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(userLoginDTO.getEmail() + "   " + userLoginDTO.getPassword() );

        // Authentication
        boolean isAuthenticated = authenticationProvider.authenticate(userLoginDTO);
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
        if (principal != null) {
            String username = principal.getName();
            if (userLoginDTO.getEmail().equals(username)) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Already authenticated").build();
            }
        }

        UserReadOnlyDTO userReadOnlyDTO = userService.findUserByEmail(userLoginDTO.getEmail());
        String username = userReadOnlyDTO.getName();

        // Create a JWT token for current user
        String token = jwtService.generateToken(userLoginDTO.getEmail(), username);
        AuthenticationResponseDTO authenticationResponseDTO = new AuthenticationResponseDTO(token);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(authenticationResponseDTO).build();
    }
}

The Problem
For /auth/login, since it's a public path, the JwtAuthenticationFilter skips setting the SecurityContext. However, the injected Principal is not null but incomplete (getName() returns null), leading to confusing behavior.
If I check for principal.getName() != null in the /login resource, I still encounter the following error:
RESTEASY002005: Failed executing POST /auth/login
RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: java.security.Principal


What am i missing here?
Thanks in advance!
Adding null checks in the /login resource:
if (principal == null || principal.getName() == null) {
    System.out.println("Principal is null or name is null.");
}


But it keep failing for the same error

RESTEASY002005: Failed executing POST /auth/login
RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: java.security.Principal


The @Context Principal principal requires a Principal resource in the REST context, but not found. (BTW, @Context will be deprecated and replaced by CDI @Inject in the future)
For JWT authorization in Jakarta EE, a customized REST filter is a good solution, I also used it before. Check my example codes here, https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-jaxrs-sample/tree/master/jwt/src/main/java/com/hantsylab/example/ee7/blog/security.
But for modern Jakarta EE applications, to protect HTTP endpoints, you can use the MP JWT directly, https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-jwt.html. (Hope JWT authorization will be part of Jakarta EE 12 soon)

Thank you for the response! very helpful
